# Cannot find `glutin` in `glium` when using Conrod

Tags: rust, glium

I am attempting to add a GUI to a [small project of mine](https://github.com/jmcph4/rsnotes) using Conrod. I have managed to work my way down to 3 compilation errors:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Could not find `glutin` in `glium`
  --> src/support/mod.rs:88:53
   |
88 |     pub fn next(&mut self, events_loop: &mut glium::glutin::EventsLoop) -> Vec<glium::glutin::Event> {
   |                                                     ^^^^^^ Could not find `glutin` in `glium`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Could not find `glutin` in `glium`
  --> src/support/mod.rs:88:87
   |
88 |     pub fn next(&mut self, events_loop: &mut glium::glutin::EventsLoop) -> Vec<glium::glutin::Event> {
   |                                                                                       ^^^^^^ Could not find `glutin` in `glium`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Could not find `glutin` in `glium`
   --> src/support/mod.rs:106:24
    |
106 |                 glium::glutin::ControlFlow::Break
    |                        ^^^^^^ Could not find `glutin` in `glium`
```

I've studied the examples that ship with Conrod (particularly the `text_edit.rs` example) and have successfully compiled and run them. As far as I can tell, they use the same techniques (as my code is directly inspired by their examples), yet does not suffer from the unresolved imports of `glutin`.

Furthermore, I cannot seem to find any reference to `glutin` in the project directory itself:

```
$> pwd
~/dev/conrod/src
$> tree.
    .
├── backend
│   ├── gfx.rs
│   ├── glium.rs
│   ├── mod.rs
│   ├── piston
│   │   ├── draw.rs
│   │   ├── event.rs
│   │   └── mod.rs
│   └── winit.rs
├── border.rs
├── color.rs
├── cursor.rs
├── event.rs
├── graph
│   ├── algo.rs
│   ├── depth_order.rs
│   └── mod.rs
├── guide
│   ├── chapter_1.rs
│   ├── chapter_2.rs
│   └── mod.rs
├── image.rs
├── input
│   ├── global.rs
│   ├── mod.rs
│   ├── state.rs
│   └── widget.rs
├── label.rs
├── lib.rs
├── position
│   ├── matrix.rs
│   ├── mod.rs
│   ├── range.rs
│   └── rect.rs
├── render.rs
├── tests
│   ├── global_input.rs
│   ├── mod.rs
│   ├── ui.rs
│   └── widget_input.rs
├── text.rs
├── theme.rs
├── ui.rs
├── utils.rs
└── widget
    ├── bordered_rectangle.rs
    ├── builder.rs
    ├── button.rs
    ├── canvas.rs
    ├── collapsible_area.rs
    ├── drop_down_list.rs
    ├── envelope_editor.rs
    ├── file_navigator
    │   ├── directory_view.rs
    │   └── mod.rs
    ├── graph
    │   ├── mod.rs
    │   └── node.rs
    ├── grid.rs
    ├── id.rs
    ├── list.rs
    ├── list_select.rs
    ├── matrix.rs
    ├── mod.rs
    ├── number_dialer.rs
    ├── plot_path.rs
    ├── primitive
    │   ├── image.rs
    │   ├── line.rs
    │   ├── mod.rs
    │   ├── point_path.rs
    │   ├── shape
    │   │   ├── circle.rs
    │   │   ├── mod.rs
    │   │   ├── oval.rs
    │   │   ├── polygon.rs
    │   │   ├── rectangle.rs
    │   │   └── triangles.rs
    │   └── text.rs
    ├── range_slider.rs
    ├── rounded_rectangle.rs
    ├── scrollbar.rs
    ├── scroll.rs
    ├── slider.rs
    ├── tabs.rs
    ├── text_box.rs
    ├── text_edit.rs
    ├── title_bar.rs
    ├── toggle.rs
└── xy_pad.rs
```

For reference, my `Cargo.toml` also includes `glutin` as a dependency:

```
[features]
default = ["winit", "glium"]

winit = ["conrod/winit"]
glium = ["conrod/glium"]

[dependencies]
conrod = "^0.57"
find_folder = "*"
glutin = "*"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review how to create a [MCVE]. Specifically, you should be able to provide a **small** piece of code that reproduces the same error. I would guess it would only need to be one file  about 5 lines long. Hint: make it so this has the same error `fn x(_: glium::glutin::EventsLoop) {}`

Comment: It's super hard to tell exactly where your error is given that you don't include your `use` and `extern crate` statements, but my best guess is that you aren't depending on `glium`, or the "glium" module you're trying to use isn't actually `glium`? There's a `conrod::backend::glium` module which _is not the same as `glium`_. Since you aren't depending on `glium = 0.19` in your Cargo.toml, I assume you're trying to use conrod's glium module rather than glium itself? The _actual_ `glium` crate does have a `glutin` property.

Comment: @daboross your comment solved the problem. Basically I was trying to use `conrod::backend::glium` insterad of `glium::glutin`. I attribute this to myself but also the misleading Conrod example code (personally I think their documentation is lacking). I'd like to mark this as answered, care to post it as such?

Comment: I'll do that - glad it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a misconception about the module structure of `conrod` and `glium`.

The conrod crate has a number of backend modules, containing utility functions for each of the different backends. `conrod::backend::glium` is this module for glium, and it contains structures and things useful for using conrod with glium.

In your case, however, I think you mistook this module for *`glium` itself*.

`glium` is a separate crate from conrod, and you'll need to depend on it much like you depend on `glutin`. `glium` does indeed have a `glium::conrod` property, so if you do pull it in with `extern crate glium;` rather than using `conrod::backend::glium`, it should "just work"!

You'll need to add some line `glium = 0.x` in your `Cargo.toml` as well, but that should be trivial.